# How can I look up symbols in XCode archives?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, lldb

How can I look up symbols (eg. `0x10534843f`) in programs archived with XCode?

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click on the archive in the organizer in XCode, select “Show in Finder”
2. Open a Terminal in the folder
3. Type `lldb` to start the debugger
4. load the executable with debug symbols: `target create --no-dependents --arch x86_64 Products/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp --symfile dSYMs/MyApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MyApp` (make sure you use the correct paths; if you provide an incorrect symfile, you'll receive no warning)
5. Type `image list` and validate the UUID of the binary matches your crash report to make sure you're looking at the right archive (see loaded images section at the bottom of crash/sample report)
6. Load the image at the correct location: `target modules load --file Products/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp __TEXT 0x123456` (replace 0x123456 with the load address from the report)
7. Now you can look up symbols using `image lookup -a 0x105346367`
8. Use the verbose option to show more details: `image lookup -v -a 0x105346367`